# Google map not shown in .net img

Tags: .net, image, google-maps

I want to show a dynamic google map on a .net web page. Having not much experience with this, I once did it with a link which worked well:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.de/maps?f=q&hl=de&q=Winterhuder Weg 11,Hamburg 22085">Go to Map</a>
```

When I try to put this into an img control, the map is **not shown**:

```
<img runat="server" id="googleMapsImage" width="460" alt="" height="270" 
    src="http://maps.google.de/maps?f=q&hl=de&q=Winterhuder Weg 11,Hamburg 22085" />
```

If I use some static map, it works:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because the link you are referencing returns HTML, and not an image.